# Maximum values per day from data with different dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, pivot-table, worksheet-function

I have data taken at different times on different days, for example:

```
dateTimeRead(YYYY-MM-DD HH-mm-ss)   rain_value(mm)  air_pressure(hPa)
1/2/2015 0:00                       0               941.5675
1/2/2015 0:15                       0               941.4625
1/2/2015 0:30                       0               941.3
1/2/2015 0:45                       0               941.2725
1/2/2015 1:00                       0.2             941.12
1/2/2015 1:15                       0               940.8625
1/2/2015 1:30                       0               940.7575
1/2/2015 1:45                       0               940.6075
1/2/2015 2:00                       0               940.545
1/2/2015 2:15                       0               940.27
1/2/2015 2:30                       0               940.2125
1/2/2015 16:15                      0               940.625
1/2/2015 16:30                      0               940.69
1/2/2015 16:45                      0               940.6175
1/2/2015 17:00                      0               940.635
1/2/2015 19:00                      0               941.9975
1/2/2015 20:45                      0               942.7925
1/2/2015 21:00                      0               942.745
1/2/2015 21:15                      0               942.6325
1/2/2015 21:30                      0               942.735
1/2/2015 21:45                      0               942.765
1/2/2015 22:00                      0               7/30/1902
1/3/2015 2:30                       0               941.1275
1/3/2015 2:45                       0               941.125
1/3/2015 3:00                       0               940.955
1/3/2015 3:15                       0               941.035
```

There are dates with missing time stamps.

From these readings how may I extract the maximum values by day for `rain_value(mm)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fairly standard *array formula* style to provide a pseudo-MAXIF function but I prefer to use `INDEX` and enter it as a standard formula.

[image: Maximum Rainfall Daily]

With the date to be determined in F3, the formula in G3 is,

```
=MAX(INDEX(($A$2:$A$999>=$F3)*($A$2:$A$999<(F3+1))*$B$2:$B$999, , ))
```

A CSE array formula for the same thing would be something like,

```
=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$999>=$F3, IF($A$2:$A$999<$F3+1, $B$2:$B$900)))
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.

Comment: I guess if you changed it to =MAX(INDEX(($A$2:$A$999>=$F3)*($A$2:$A$999<(F4))*$B$2:$B$999, , )) you could put in any time points you chose into column F to analyse it by?

Comment: @TomSharpe - Yes, a *day* is considered numerically *1* by Excel. Times are decimal portions of a day. If you have yesterday in F3 and tomorrow in F4 then the maximum will be all of yesterday and today (e.g. greater than midnight that started yesterday and less than midnight that starts tomorrow).

Comment: Hi Guys, Thank you very much for your help. I have another problem. what if i dont want to get the max and what i need it the 30 minutes max sum of rows in column b2 per day. For example, for the 30 mins max sum for 1/2/2015 is 0.2 (sum of a4,a5 a6). Thanks in advance guys! :D

Comment: @GreylandAgno - If your request for additional information can be both considered On-Topic and short in length, I'd recommend editing your original question to suit. If the combination of the addition of revised formulas, your own effort to resolve the problem with (plus) new conditions makes it unworthy of an edit, please feel free to start a new question with sample data, formulas, original effort and expected results.

Comment: Sure Jeeped. Thanks! :D Ill just start a new post. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

An array formula may not be suitable for your particular requirement since it seems you may have very many readings. Instead I would suggest a PivotTable, with the date/Time entries parsed (Text to Columns, Fixed width) and `date` for ROWS, Max of `rain_value(mm)` for VALUES.

Comment: Or set up a new date column for the Pivot Table using a formula like =IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2)))

Comment: Good point, though I suppose like many things you could argue about whether you should need to know exactly how datetime is stored.