# Not able to find largest value in column with reference to value in adjacent column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find largest value in column B with reference to value in column A.[image: InPUT]

For example, i want to find maximum value in column B only for range where value in column A is "a"
So, result in cells(1,3) be 100.

Then, i have to find max value for range where value in column A is "b".
so, result on cells(2,3) be 110.
and so on for next values.

Final result of macro should be:

[image]

I have written code for finding maximum value in column B as below,but unable to find max value by reference:

```
Sub my()

Cells(1, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("B"))

End Sub
```

Please help.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095154/maximum-values-per-day-from-data-with-different-dates/29095675#29095675) or  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31711671/two-criteria-minif-and-maxif-formula/31712035#31712035) or 
[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460241/how-do-i-find-the-max-min-values-of-multiple-groups-in-an-excel/31461585#31461585) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439546/use-set-of-keywords-to-extract-values-from-second-worksheet/31439791#31439791) with [Evaluate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for macro:

```
{=MAX(IF(A$1:A$9999="a",B$1:B$9999))}
```

this will find the largest "a" value and

```
{=MAX(IF(A$1:A$9999="b",B$1:B$9999))}
```

this the largest "b"-value.

Please note, that this is an array formula, so enter it with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` instead of the usual `Enter`, this means you don't have to type the `{}`. This only indicates, that this is an array formula.

Comment: Thanks for your great help. It's working fine. But how to do it in VBA?

Comment: @Abhijeet - Perhaps a good old fashioned [Application.Evaluate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx). Marco - given that this is an array formula and rows should be cut down as far as possible, limit them by the last number in column (nothing below that is important), e.g. `=MAX(IF(A$1:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1e99, B:B))="a",B$1:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1e99, B:B))))` as a CSE.

Comment: @Jeeped, you are right, should have mentioned it that 9999 should either be adjusted according, or like you suggested looking for it dynamically. I would maybe substitute the `MATCH` part with `COUNTA(A:A)` for readability.

Comment: @Abhijeet In VBA you could achieve it like this: `Range("C1").FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(A$1:A$9999=""a"",B$1:B$9999))"`

Comment: @Jeeped , Thanks for your valuable help.

Comment: Marco - The [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) is faster than a [COUNTA function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/counta-function-47239e46-e523-40f4-94d7-fa2e1711fd4a) and returns the last number (in that configuration) rather than the total number of text and numbers which may be artificaly low if blanks are involved.

Comment: @Jeeped good catch! And I didn't know that `MATCH` is faster than `COUNTA` thanks for the information!